# Show loading window

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, window, loading

My application in WPF loads external resources, so I want to show a loading form while the program is loading.

I tried to create the form, and show before the loading code, and close when loading ended.

```
private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
     LoadForm lf = new LoadForm();
     lf.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;

     // Al code that delays application loading

     lf.Close();
}
```

But the only thing I get is that the form is showed when loading progress is complete and immediately closes.

I think that I need to use System.Threading but not sure.

Thanks.

**Note** I load all application external resources in Window_Loaded() method and not in the main class method.

Comment: I think you are in the right path when you think about threads. You should open your form, and load all of the stuff in a different thread. That way your application is responsive, and it wont lock the UI.

Comment: What about a splash screen? Would that work?

Answer (score 6):

You should look at this MSDN article on creating a [SplashScreen](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc656886.aspx) in WPF. Essentially you add the Image you want to show to your project and set the Build Action to SplashScreen it will show when your program starts and disappear when your Main Application Window is shown.

---

You could also try importing the `System.ComponentModel` Class and use [BackgroundWorker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx) to Show your Loading Form, it will allow you to retain responsiveness of your UI.

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    Window1 splash;
    BackgroundWorker bg;
    public MainWindow()
    {

        InitializeComponent();

        bg = new BackgroundWorker();
        bg.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(bg_DoWork);
        bg.RunWorkerCompleted += new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(bg_RunWorkerCompleted);

    }

    void bg_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        splash.Hide();
    }

    void bg_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(10000);
    }


    private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        splash = new Window1();
        splash.Show();
        bg.RunWorkerAsync();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but first I have a window to type user and password (loads fast), then, when is autentified in the program all the stuff is loaded, but this is useful for other of my project that don't have a Splash window.

Comment: @SteelersMan See if my edit on using `BackgroundWorker` helps

Comment: Thanks, this was very useful for I was trying to do, you helped two times. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: @SteelersMan You are welcome, glad it helped.  If one of the answers answered your question you should click the check mark to mark your question as answered.

Comment: @SteelersMan Just for the record, I wasn't prompting you to choose my answer, just the answer that answered your question. though it is appreciated :)

Answer (score 2):

You should put your time consuming code in a background thread (for that you can use BackgroundWorker, Task or Async Await, depending on your dot net framework version)

```
private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    LoadForm lf = new LoadForm();
    lf.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
    //start the time consuming task in another thread
}


HeavyTaskCompleteEvent()
{
     lf.Close();
}
```

Also look out for the best way to show loading screen. You can show some animation in the main window as well. I don't think showing a form is the best way.

Answer (score 1):

I made a Loader class a while ago you could use. It shows a Window while doing your loading-method, closes it when completed and gives you the output of the method:

```
public class Loader<TActionResult>:FrameworkElement
{
    private Func<TActionResult> _execute;
    public TActionResult Result { get; private set; }
    public delegate void OnJobFinished(object sender, TActionResult result);
    public event OnJobFinished JobFinished;

    public Loader(Func<TActionResult> execute)
    {
        if (execute == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("execute");

        _execute = execute;
    }

    private Window GetWaitWindow()
    {
        Window waitWindow = new Window { Height = 100, Width = 200, WindowStartupLocation = WindowStartupLocation.CenterScreen, WindowStyle = WindowStyle.None };
        waitWindow.Content = new TextBlock { Text = "Please Wait", FontSize = 30, FontWeight = FontWeights.Bold, HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Center, VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Center };

        return waitWindow;
    }

    public void Load(Window waitWindow = null)
    {
        if (waitWindow == null)
        {
            waitWindow = GetWaitWindow();
        }
        BackgroundWorker worker = new BackgroundWorker();
        worker.DoWork += delegate
        {
            Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(delegate { waitWindow.ShowDialog(); }));
            Result = _execute();
            Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(delegate() { waitWindow.Close(); }));
        };
        worker.RunWorkerCompleted += delegate
        {
            worker.Dispose();
            if (JobFinished != null)
            {
                JobFinished(this, Result);
            }
        };
        worker.RunWorkerAsync();
    }
}
```

How to use it:

```
Loader<TResult> loader = new Loader<TResult>(MethodName);
loader.JobFinished += new Loader<TResult>.OnJobFinished(loader_JobFinished);
loader.Load();

void loader_JobFinished(object sender, TResult result)
{
    // do whatever you want with your result here
}
```

Comment: How can I pass parameters into the MethodName method?