# how do I show a loading window in WPF while performing Entity Framework operations with 1 DBContext?

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework, backgroundworker

I have an application in WPF (MVVM) and in my viewmodel I need to save some new entries. This is a large application with several tabs and uses 1 central database context (EF 5).

When saving the new entries, each entry is programmatically validated and then inserted or updated in the database via the DBContext.

Each time the Save button is pressed this action is performed for over a hundred entries and takes a few seconds....

While saving I would like to show a loading window....and I though of doing this via a backgroundworker thread...
Something like here: 
[Show loading window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13835790/show-loading-window)

Unfortunately I'm getting AccessViolationExceptions with Entity Framework since I'm only using one and the same DBContext...

Is there any possibility to show the loading window while keeping 1 DBContext?

Thank you !

Comment: One `DbContext` for the entire application is a pretty bad Anti-Pattern in Entity Framework.  You may want to rethink that.

Comment: Also don't use backgroundworker, use async-await with Task api instead.

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to show you how I do:

```
        EstaOcupado = true;

        var taskSalvar = Task.Run(() =>
        {
            var proxyFactory = ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<IServiceClientFactory>();
            var proxy = proxyFactory.GetCadastrosGeraisService();

            proxy.Open();

            caixa = Boot.Mapeador.Map<CaixaModel, Caixa>(Caixa);
            caixa = proxy.SalvarCaixa(caixa);
            proxy.Close();
        });

        try
        {
            taskSalvar.Wait();
            Caixa.EndEdit();
            EstaEmEdicao = false;

        }
        catch (AggregateException ae)
        {
            var msg = WcfProxy.HandleServiceExceptions(ae);

            Resolve<IMessageVisualizer>()
                .Show("Atenção", msg,
                    new CustomMessageVisualizerOptions() {Dialog = DialogType.Alert, Prompt = MessageButtons.OK});
        }
        finally
        {
            EstaOcupado = false;

            Caixa = Boot.Mapeador.Map<Caixa, CaixaModel>(caixa);
        }
```

My "EstaOcupado" (IsBusy) property is binded to a control mine which shows a loading animation. As I'm using Task, my taskSalvar runs in background, allowing my UI to be updated. Please, try this structure.

Comment: I believe this will just create another thread and leave me with the same issue.